# Pentaho merge rows (diff) not showing "changed"

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-design-studio, pentaho-cde

I've got this steps

[image]

The `merge rows diff` is configured as follow

[image]

But when a update is detected it doesn't show the "changed" tag, it show two rows, a deleted and a new

[image]

The [documentation](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Synchronize+after+merge) says that a "changed" tag should be displayed on the update case. Could anybody help me on this?

I've try with the sort by id steps, and I currently have a `SORT BY id` on the table imput query. But nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, a friend saw the problem. The `key fields` and the `value fields` definition was all wrong. This is the right way to configure the `merge row (diff)` step:

[image]

The `Get value fields' button confuses me. Now I've got the right result

[image]

Comment: yes, that's it. The keys are the fields to compare records to determine which ones are new or deleted; the values are the fields to compare to determine which ones are identical or changed. The  structure of both input streams must mathc (same field names, same data types)

Comment: God bless you all three you, your friend and @nsousa thank you!